# What to do when my answer is not accepted?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

What should I do if an answer of mine is not accepted? The answer is right, it solves the problem, it has been tested by me and by the user (I also replied to other small questions asked  by the user in the comments). But he doesn't accept my reply as the best one, nor has he at least said thanks. It has happened to me more then once. What should I do?

Comment: Move on. There is nothing to do.

Comment: Acceptance of answers is entirely up to the OP. If they don't accept your answer, you cannot make them. Just move on, it's only 15 points.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You're completely right, but you have also forgotten how important 15 rep is to someone on 46 rep.

Comment: Keep at it, like I did (and do), and you'll eventually get shiny badges like "Unsung Hero".  When graciousness costs only a mouse-click, it's shameful how many will not spend it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's not for the  15 points (I got 15 point just asking this question), this is a question answer/question community: asking, replying and vote it's an implicit mechanism in it. It's true, I can't make them accept, I just wanted to know if there was some solution..

Comment: @Alessandro, I sympathise - I sometimes wonder if new helpers get put off in the early days by an audience who either (a) don't know about acceptance and upvoting, (b) do know about it but are not aware of the psychological benefit helpers receive when their answer is acknowledged in this way, or (c) lack the capacity to express gratitude generally.

Comment: If you want to increase your reputation (and I can understand why new users do) then concentrate on good questions from higher-rep users. Personally, I like to help beginners, but I think the point rewards are lower in this category; however, once you have a bit of 'rep' behind you, collecting it does tend to become less important. There is satisfaction to be had in just helping, too `:)`.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Before you decide to write an answer, look at the OP profile: does he accept answers? Does he upvote good answers? Some users don't appreciate your time spent on the answer, so don't be disappointed.

I also have the feeling that some C# or Python answers with low effort and low knowledge have many more upvotes than similar javascript tagged answer. But at least you may hope for Tenacious and Unsung hero badge.

Comment: yes maybe it's better to look at the profile before to choose whether to reply or not but, if I decide to reply, I cannot give an "half" reply. "tenacious" seems the right term to describe the situation and probably it's what remain to be expected.

Comment: Answer the question not the OP. What you're suggesting is bad for the site's over all goal of building a library of detailed answers to every question about programming.

Comment: @apaul34208 I agree - I have updated the answer to be "politically correct".